# "No se puede conectar" vs "no puede conectarse"

Tags: traducción, gramática, vocabulario, reflexivos

As far as I know, they're identical. And are both grammatically correct and can be used interchangeably.

Is this indeed the case?

Answer (score 3):

They *can* be identical in meaning, but that's not always the case.

*No puede conectarse* may always be rendered as *No se puede conectar* due to the phenomenon of *pronoun raising* of Spanish.  In this case, the *se* is associated with the verb *conectar*, but may be placed either with *conectar* (enclitically, because it's in the infinitive) or *poder* (proclitically, because it's conjugated).

However, *se* need not necessarily be associated with *conectar*.  It is also possible that the *se* is associated with the verb *poder*, forming an impersonal statement.  In this case, because pronouns can only be raised and not lowered, there is no other alternative rendering and only "no se puede conectar" works.

Comment: what'll be the difference in the meaning when "se" is associated with conectar and when with poner?

Comment: With conectar, "[something] is unable to connect (itself) / get connected".  With poder, "It is not possible to connect / One cannot connect"

Comment: are you saying that `no se puede conectar` and `no puede conectarse` have  different meahings or conotations?

Comment: I'm saying that *no se puede conectar* has two potential interpretations, only one of which is equivalent to *no puede conectarse*.  As such, *no puede conectarse* can **always** be rewritten as *no se puede conectar*, but *no se puede conectar* cannot **always** be rewritten as *no puede conectarse*.

Comment: @guifa La diferencia es cuando uno quiere usar ‘no se puede conectar’ como impersonal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are the same.

Also you can say:

**No se conecta**

Even informally (opinion as native spanish speaker) **No conecta**

Comment: You can check the popularity of each for googling "No conecta" / "No se conecta" / etc and looking at the amount of results.

Comment: I'm not asking how to say that I can't connect

Comment: I was not saying how you have to say

Comment: I'm not saying that you said that. I said that you didn't answer my question